# How to do full postback to same page in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a page which can be linked to with a parameter...and when you are in the page, you can select an item from a datatable - from which I want to be able to post back the same page with a full redirect so the query parameter gets rewritten.

At the moment, when I post back to the same page, it always seems to be seen as a partial postback as the postback is from the current page.  How do I do a full redirect to the same page, or is it not possible to get the parameter in the URL overwritten.

I can open items without a full refresh, but if they have entered the page via another page, then the URL has the parameter in it...later when they refresh, it pulls in the original data from the parameter...

This is in my data table, ,and this is placed in the same page I am redirecting to.  I have tried outcome and action...!

```
<f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton id="openMyTask" value="Open Task" icon="ui-icon-search" action="/pages/customer/customerTasks?includeViewParams=false;faces-redirect=true" >
<f:param name="admsTaskId" value="#{customerTaskBean.selectedTaskId}"></f:param>
</p:commandButton>
</f:facet>
```

Many thanks

SM

Comment: Is `p:commandButton` primefaces or plain JSF ? Primefaces is not tagged in your question so please let me know and I'll update my answer as needed.

Comment: Hi, I have tried p:buton and p:commandButton.  I am using Primefaces, thanks.

Comment: Ok, and you want to reload the page correct when you choose an item ? Also, are you always going to be pointing to that page ater clicking the button ?

Comment: Also, are you using JSF 2.0 or lower ?

Comment: Please take the time to understand my comments. You will run into trouble in the future. I'm only insisting because I'm concerned. Don't just be happy because something works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redisplay the same page with query strings in the URL then `use p:button`.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
     <p:button id="openMyTask" includeViewParams="true" value='Open Task'>
        <f:param name='admsTaskId' value='#{customerTaskBean.selectedTaskId}'/>
    </p:button>
</f:facet>
```

`includeViewParams="true"` ensure that you are including the parameters sent from the previous page.

The second line is overwriting the values. If you have more values you want to overwrite then you include more `f:param`.

Notice also that I did not specify an `outcome`. Since you want to go back to the same page it will do so when `outcome` is not specified in this case.

**Note**: Judging by your answer, it looks to me like you are not trying to do a postback. As BalusC stated from the comments: "a "postback" is a POST request to same URL as where the page with the form is requested from".

Comment: Hi,I dont want to send the parameters from the previous page, as I am making a new selection once in the page and need to replace the parameter, so do a full redirect to itself.

Comment: @user1754307 you mean go to the same page but with query string parameters, right? If that's what you're looking for then this is the answer. Still, I don't really like that approach since it lets the application open to users that can post whatever they want in the query string.

Comment: You are not sending the parameters from the previous page. You are including all the arguments and overwriting their values.

Comment: `<p:button>` doesn't create a postback at all (a "postback" is a POST request to same URL as where the page with the form is requested from, this is the default case for JSF `<h:form>`). Instead, the `<p:button>` creates a GET request. I must however admit that OP is not clear in what he *actually* needs, so you're saved from a downvote for actually giving the wrong answer to the question as concretely stated in the title.

Comment: @BalusC You are right. It's a typo on my end. I will fix. However I actually the whole 'GET' thing on my comments to him below. I'll reword it. Thanks.

Comment: @BalusC Fixed. Also you can't say I gave him the wrong answer when the title and the description don't fit. The OP needs to go back and edit his post.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTasks" value

="#{customerTasksBean.customerTasks}" var="task" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{task.id}"
                    paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
                    editable="false" rowStyleClass="#{customerTasksBean.taskStatusService.getTaskRowClass(task)}">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{customerTasksBean.onMyTaskSelect}" update="openTask" />

                    <f:facet name="header">  
                            Current Request Pool
                     </f:facet>

                    <p:column headerText="Task ID" sortBy="#{task.id}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.id}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Task Type" sortBy="#{task.type.toString()}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.type.toString()}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Created For" sortBy="#{task.createdFor.fullName}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.createdFor.fullName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Submitted" sortBy="#{task.createdDate}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.createdDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Required By" sortBy="#{task.requiredByDate}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.requiredByDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Days to completion" sortBy="#{aDMSBean.taskRequiredDays(task)}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myTasksBean.taskStatusService.getDaysLeftToTaskCompletion(task)} " />
                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Comment">
                        <h:outputLabel id="taskCustomerComment" value="Hover mouse over" />
                        <p:tooltip for="taskCustomerComment" value="#{task.customerComment}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:button id="openTask" value="Open Task" icon="ui-icon-search"
                            outcome="/pages/customer/customerTasks?includeViewParams=false;faces-redirect=true">
                            <f:param name="admsTaskId" value="#{customerTasksBean.selectedTaskId}">
                            </f:param>

                        </p:button>

                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Look at my answer. You don't have to do all of that especially `includeViewParams=false;faces-redirect=true`. You're not doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: p:button is already doing a 'GET' request instead of post right ? so `faces-redirect=true"` is not needed. You're only overwriting the values sent right ? `includeViewParams=false`also not needed. What if you had 2 values sent and you only wanted to overwrite one but keep the other ? When you click on the button you're going to lose one of your `GET` parameters

Comment: Lastly if you are just refreshing the same page  `outcome="/pages/customer/customerTasks` is also not needed. Just don't include an `outcome` and it will reload the same page by default. Much more elegant instead of hard coding. But if it works for you it works I guess.

Comment: Hi, I will try your method tomorrow.  My concern is that I need the phsyical URL to change, otherwise refreshing the browser uses old parameters...also, It has to be a full post and not a partial postback, as I have logic operating for full postbacks and not partials....so whatever gives me all that, I am happy to use.  It is working for me at the moment as I need it to, but would like to do it correctly and not by "guessing"!!  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding the problem correctly, the only time you'll use old values is when you hit refresh (the actual refresh button). Whenever you click on the button after making your selections, your EL expression will be evaluated and the value for `adminTask` will be overwritten by the newly evaluated value. Let me know if you have issues I guess.

Comment: yes, but I dont want them to hit refresh and go to a task which may not be the one they are working on, just because it is in the URL.  This is why I was thinking of faces-redirect, so the URL gets rewritten

Comment: faces-redirect only generates new `GET` request. It's not rewriting anything. Also, `<p:button>` is also creating `GET` requests so you're doing double the work. To overwrite **all** values sent from a previous `GET` in a URL you need to include them first `includeViewParams="true"`and then overwrite them with `<f:param>`

Comment: If you do are not overwriting values sent from a previous request then yes `includeViewParams="false"` makes sense.